# Share access to Git repository on local DevOps server for external user

Tags: git, devops, azure-devops-server-2019

I would like to give a external user access to our Git repository on a local installed DevOps server and wonder how i do this in best practice?

All the regular users authenticate to our DevOps server using their domain user accounts. I would not like to give this external user an domain account to access our local Devops server and wonder if there is a way an external user can connect anyway?
This external user shall only have access to the Git repository and not be able to see any tasks or any other work at our git repository.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi s0ckan, Does my answer help? Please check it and kindly let us know the result, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Currently external users cannot access to collections if he has no domain account in Azure DevOps Server. The feature: [Add external users to your organization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/add-external-user?view=azure-devops) can only be available in Azure DevOps Service.

I am afraid that you still need to grant this user an domain account, and if you just add this user to project Readers group, by default he has only read permission for repositories but cannot contribute to, see: [Project-level groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/permissions?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#project-level-groups) for details.

If you don’t want this user to view work items, you could disable related permissions for this user by following this doc: [Set permissions and access for work tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/set-permissions-access-work-tracking?view=azure-devops-2019).